# Change domain in call to window.history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, cross-domain-policy

I have a small multilingual site organised as multiple subdomains of the same domain, each prefixed with the language's ISO 639 code. There is also a general `www.` subdomain with the logic to handle redirection to an appropriate language subdomain, based on the languages specified by the user agent, as well as processesing legacy URLs. All domains point to the same instance of the same application running on some relatively modern version of IIS on Windows (I don't remember exactly, because it is a hosted environment).

Everything works fine, but I would like to achieve a smoother transition when the user goes from one language to another. I have set the pages up so that I can retrieve them complete or only with the relevant translateable contents depending on the URL I use to access them, so that I can load the full page in a standard request, but only the relevant pieces via AJAX when I need the same contents in a different language. I then place those contents in their appropriate page locations, and finally cross-fade between the old language and the new language.

The visual effect is nice, but I need to update the browser's address bar accordingly and that's where I run into problems, because that seems to breach the designed behaviour of `window.history.pushState()`. I realise that allowing scripts to happily change the user's address bar in somewhat hidden ways would be the source of countless security problems, but it is a bit frustrating to have an application where all those subdomains are simply different values in a string variable, and with all the logic implemented to produce "seamless" content translations, only to stumble upon something as simple as changing the URL displayed in the browser's address bar.

Can anyone think of a solution or a workaround to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: This would violate same origin, not sure if pushState cares about CORS. Also see [`document.domain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain). If domain doesn't solve the issue, consider keeping track of these things in sessionStorage, rewriting your html links and then re-populating history on next navigation onto the other domain. Otherwise move to using path, not subdomain

Comment: Hi @PaulS., thanks for your quick comment. I am not sure I understand your first suggestion (sessionStorage, rewriting links, etc.) Could you please elaborate further? Thank you!